# RVM: Warning! PATH is not properly set up

Tags: bash, ubuntu-14.04, rvm

I am on a Ubuntu 14.04 LTS machine running rvm 1.27.0. 
When I run `rvm list` I receive the following warning:

```
Warning! PATH is not properly set up, '/home/asarluhi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin' is not at first place,
     usually this is caused by shell initialization files - check them for 'PATH=...' entries,
     it might also help to re-add RVM to your dotfiles: 'rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles',
     to fix temporarily in this shell session run: 'rvm use ruby-2.3.1'.
```

The output of `echo $PATH` is:

`/home/asarluhi/bin:/home/asarluhi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin:/home/asarluhi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/bin:/home/asarluhi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin:/home/asarluhi/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/asarluhi/.rvm/bin:/home/asarluhi/.rvm/bin:/home/asarluhi/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/home/asarluhi/.rvm/bin:/home/asarluhi/.rvm/bin:/home/asarluhi/.rvm/bin:/home/asarluhi/.rvm/bin`

As you can see, in effect `/home/asarluhi/bin` comes first and also `/home/asarluhi/.rvm/bin` is repeated 7 times.  
The last two lines of my `~/.bashrc` file are:

```
### Added by the Heroku Toolbelt
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/heroku/bin"

export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
```

The last lines of my `~/.profile` file are:

```
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi

export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting

export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting

export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

The content of my `~/.bash_profile` is:

```
export GITAWAREPROMPT=~/.bash/git-aware-prompt
source "${GITAWAREPROMPT}/main.sh"

[[ -s "$HOME/.profile" ]] && source "$HOME/.profile" # Load the default .profile

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

To remove the exceeding `/home/asarluhi/.rvm/bin` i might probably try to remove the duplicate lines in `~/.profile`. However I do not know how to solve the `Warning! PATH is not properly set up` issue. I tried to change the order of `$PATH` in `~/.profile` for my private bin and for rvm as follows:

```
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin"
fi

export PATH="$HOME/.rvm/bin:$PATH" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
```

I also changed the order of $PATH in `~/bashrc` as I did for `~/.profile`.
However I keep receiving the same warning.
As you can see, now there is /home/asarluhi/.rvm/bin at first place:

```
~ $ echo $PATH
/home/asarluhi/.rvm/bin:/home/asarluhi/.rvm/bin:/home/asarluhi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin:/home/asarluhi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/bin:/home/asarluhi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin:/home/asarluhi/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/asarluhi/.rvm/bin:/home/asarluhi/.rvm/bin:/home/asarluhi/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/home/asarluhi/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

The only necessary edit to the config dotfiles is to prepend `$PATH` to `$HOME/bin` in `~/.profile` as follows:

```
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin"
fi
```